# How can restrict a user to access some section of my application in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have different type of users in my application. Ex: Super Admin, Client, Staff and HR.
Now I want to give all access to Super Admin and some for Client and some for Staff and some for HR also.

Lets say I have 3 section 
a) Manage Staff
b) Manage Clients
c) Manage Projects
d) Manage Designation

Now I want to give access super admin a,b,c & d And for Client only C And For Staff Only c & d And for HR only a.

I have done it by checking the **User type** form my user table. **(Not Right Way)**

Lets Say I have a URL ***localhost/myApp/staff***  [ this can be access by **Super Admin**]
But when I logged in as **Client** and I hit the above URL then He/She is able to get the list of staffs, Which I want to restrict and redirect back him with some message.

How can I achive this in Laravel 5.4. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Before down voting my question let me know why?

Answer (score 1):

In the function for the staff url check the type of user:

```
function staff(){
    if(Auth::user ! = 'super-admin')
        return redirect('/')
    }
    else{
       //show the staff
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use middleware for that.

See in the doc:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware

A little example

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
  $user = $request->user();

  if ($user && $user->isAdmin())
  {
    return $next($request);
  }
  return new RedirectResponse(url('/home'));

}
}
```

With a middleware like that , if the user is Admin he can go on the page if not it will be redirect on the homepage.

The isAdmin is a function , you gonna need to create in your user Model like that.

```
public function isAdmin()
 {
   return $this->groups->name =='Admin';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need check this page out [Authenticate A User Instance](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#other-authentication-methods).

Authenticate A User Instance

If you need to log an existing user instance into your application, you may call the login method with the user instance. The given object must be an implementation of the Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable contract.

```
Auth::login($user);
// Login and "remember" the given user...
Auth::login($user, true);`
```

Of course, you may specify the guard instance you would like to use:

```
Auth::guard('admin')->login($user);
```

You can follow the Laravel documentation or add a new field called 'role' or what ever to authenticate.